# Entity framework DbContext.SaveChangesAsync very slow, and database not updated if AutoDetectChangesEnabled set to false

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

A have a two-table database (very simple). One has around 200,000 entries, and the other around 100,000.

I'm finding that calls to DbContext.SaveChangesAsync, using EntityFramework, are extremely slow, even when I'm only updating one or two rows in the database.

I've tried setting AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false just before calling SaveChangesAsync, and this speeds things up massively (down to just a couple of hundred milliseconds), however, when I do so changes which I've made aren't committed to the database - which kind of makes sense given that I've probably disabled change tracking.

Are there any alternative approaches? It seems ridiculous that it should take a second or two to update a single row in the database (which is what it's taking with AutoDetectChangesEnabled set to true).

Any help much appreciated.